# How to perform Update or Delete in list using Mongo DB Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I was learning **Mongo DB** and in that i have following doubt. Please help

I have a class like following example

```
public class NoteUser
{
    private int userid{get;set;}
    private List<notes> notes{get;set;}
}
```

And now i have a context class to read from the database. And i also have one repository class to read the values from this context class, and this class have the functions like following

```
private bool DeleteNoteByUserId(int userId, int noteId)
{
    //Here i need to delete the note which having id as noteId for user 
    //who having the id as userId
}

private bool UpdateNoteByUserId(int userId, int noteId, Note objNote)
{
    //Here i need to perform update the note with objNote which having id as 
    //noteId for user who having the id as userId
}
```

How do i code it using MongoDBDriver in my repository class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a note (nested object) you have to use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator and specify filtering condition. In C# you can use following code:

```
var filter = Builders<NoteUser>.Filter.Eq(x => x.userid, userId);
var update = Builders<NoteUser>.Update.PullFilter(f => f.notes, p => p.noteid == noteId);

Col.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

To update nested object you can use [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and specify all properties. Value `-1` represents the note that is matched by filter part.

```
var filter = Builders<NoteUser>.Filter.And(Builders<NoteUser>.Filter.Eq(x => x.userid, userId), 
    Builders<NoteUser>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.notes, f => f.noteid == noteId));

var update = Builders<NoteUser>.Update.Combine(
            Builders<NoteUser>.Update.Set(user => user.notes[-1].firstProp, note.firstProp),
            Builders<NoteUser>.Update.Set(user => user.notes[-1].another, note.another));

Col.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks Mick it worked :). Its really really tricky unless you get a good grip in Mongo query